# Objective-C best method for decrypting NSStrings from .txt file

Tags: objective-c, public-key-encryption, encryption

I've have a .txt file containing an NSString (encrypted using a private key) that my application uses (decrypted using a public key). Everything works beautifully for one string, however, if I have another NSString that I want to use I have to create another separate .txt file with that encrypted NSString. I know there has to be a way to put all the NSStrings in one file and somehow parse it, although I'm not sure how to achieve this. Could it be done using a .plist file that contains all the encrypted strings?

This is an example of the code I use to decrypt my .txt file with one NSString:

```
NSString *filePath = @"/path/to/file.txt";

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        crypto = [[MyCrypto alloc] initWithPublicKey:publicKeyData privateKey:privateKeyData];

        NSError *err;

        theString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

        if (!theString) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", err);
        }

[crypto setClearTextWithString:theString];
decryptedTextData = [crypto decrypt];
NSLog(@"Decrypted: %@", theString);

...
```

---

If someone can shed some light on the subject with an example I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you decrypting using the public key? It's normally the other way around, unless you're using it for verification rather than encryption (and even then, you would normally verify a strong hash of the file rather than the entire contents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a for loop and put your decription code inside, furthermore modify the line

```
 theString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

to the following (assuming `i` is the loop variable):

```
 theString = [array objectAtIndex:i];
```

Where you created `array` in the initialization part of your code, using:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"file.txt"];
```

The specified file also has to be a valid PLIST, an array being its root element. Example:

```
<plist>
<array>
    <string>alshnj369537nwlzba</string>
    <string>9ö876534tzhwjukmhnlfb</string>
    <!-- et cetera... -->
</array>
<plist>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you — your tips were helpful; exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help you out. :)